# Bash regex negation issue with grep

Tags: regex, bash, regex-negation

For files in directory of files with pattern file_20170321EXPR.tar.gz
with "EXPR"

as follow:

```
   12.[3-8]x
   14.[3-8]x
   23.[3-8]x
```

So sample file names as:

```
...
file_2017032312.7a.tar.gz
file_2017032312.8a.tar.gz
file_2017032314.3a.tar.gz
file_2017032314.4a.tar.gz
file_2017032314.5a.tar.gz
file_2017032314.6a.tar.gz
file_2017032323.6a.tar.gz
file_2017032323.7a.tar.gz
file_2017032323.8a.tar.gz
....
```

where files with number 3-8 are there. When I try to grep it with

```
ls | grep -E "*[1|2][2|3|4]\.[3-8]x\.tar.\gz$"
```

I also get unwanted files with  like

```
13.[3-8]x
22.[3-8]x
24.[3-8]x
```

so tried resolving it with

```
ls | grep -E "(*[1|2][2|3|4]\.[3-8]x\.tar.\gz" | grep -Ev "*13|22|24\."
```

but i am sending entire regex to a function as one argument. So need any way to combine the non-required expression in the first regex itself, something as

```
ls | grep -E "(*[1|2][2|3|4]\.[3-8]x\.tar.\gz$)|!(*13|22|24\.)"
```

which doesn't work

Comment: the file names formed as combination of EXPR values file_20170321EXPR.tar.gz becomes: file_2017032113.3x.tar.gz and file_2017032113.5x.tar.gz similarly file_2017032123.8x.tar.gz

Comment: Use `ls | grep -E "(1[24]|23)\.[3-8]x\.tar\.gz$"`

Comment: great, so file names are clear now... add the output you need for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`13.[3-8]` is returned because `[12][234]` matches `13` (and `12`, `14`, `22`, `23`, `24`). Note the `|` are treated as literal `|`, you need to remove it. You need to use a grouping construct to only allow the necessary values:

```
ls | grep -E "(1[24]|23)\.[3-8]x\.tar\.gz$"
              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

`(1[24]|23)` will only match `12`, `14` or `23`.

Also, escape the dot, not `g`, in your pattern.

**Details**:

-`(1[24]|23)` - either of the two alternatives: `12` or `14`, or (`|`) `23`
 - `\.` - a literal dot symbol
 - `[3-8]`  - a bracket expression matching `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` or`8`
 - `x\.tar\.gz` - a literal char sequence `x.tar.gz`
 - `$` - end of string.

Comment: to avoid [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), if extglob is available...  `shopt -s extglob` and `ls *@(12|14|23).[3-8]x.tar.gz`